# Safari issue with SoundCloud Widget API: SEEK event fires when pausing

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Spotted on Safari (11.0.2) :

Whenever a track is paused in the embedded player, the SC.Widget.Events.SEEK event fires just before SC.Widget.Events.PAUSE is fired.

This does not occur on FireFox, Chrome, etc. Has anybody found a way to circumvent this ? Note: this question is asked on SO by request of SoundCloud...

You can verify this here:

https://rawgit.com/igorski/soundcloud-iframe-analytics/master/dist/index.html

Debug pane in the top right will show "scrubbed" (once per play) when a SEEK event has fired for a track. You can just start playback and immediately pause it to see it happen.